# Error Reporting in WCF Service?

Tags: c#, wcf, error-reporting

I have a self hosted Net Tcp WCF service and I have the following method

```
        Subscribtion GetSubscribtion(int subscribtionId)
        {
            Subscribtion s;
            if (_subscribtionTable.TryGetValue(subscribtionId, out s) == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Not Found SessionID");//for debugging
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Subscription Id");
            }
            return s;
        }
```

Is throwing exception is a good practice for reporting erros in service programming?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In WCF you should instead be defining and throwing a FaultException. The following articles provide examples and details:

- [Exception Handling in WCF Web Service](http://blogs.msdn.com/brajens/archive/2007/04/23/exception-handling-in-wcf-web-service.aspx)
- [Developing a WCF Service - Fault Exceptions AND FAULT Contracts](http://blogit.create.pt/blogs/marcosilva/archive/2008/05/18/Developing-a-WCF-Service-_2D00_-Fault-Exceptions-AND-FAULT-Contracts.aspx)
- [Specifying and Handling Faults in Contracts and Services (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733721.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Since WCF inherently can be interoperable with non-.NET platforms, using Exceptions which is a strict .NET construct is a bad idea. It will also usually break your WCF connection, if you have one (e.g. in a session scenario).

The way to go is using interoperable SOAP faults that are transportable even to non-.NET clients.

Marc

Comment: But this is net tcp service so I am sure all clients are .Net applications

Comment: Now - yes - what about tomorrow?

Comment: And why start using the "wrong" approach, if you already know what the right approach is? You'll just end up running into problems sometime in the future.....