# Should I use response codes, exceptions or textual messages for my service responses?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, soa

I am building a WCF based service application in .Net. I am currently designing the contracts.

Should I use response codes, exceptions or textual messages for my service responses to report service result status?

They will be consumed by web applications and other systems.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992883

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error Reporting in WCF Service?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992883/error-reporting-in-wcf-service)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should take a look at FaultContracts. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.faultcontractattribute.aspx

Your Fault Contract can include a (string based) error code for client side processing, and / or a textual message for display to users.

If your service, or rather you as a service designer, don't know what a (future) client application will want to do with an error message (display or process), include both.

Comment: My only concern is that fault contracts and associated concepts are not mappable to REST services or JSON.

Comment: Have built a proof of concept that works to my specification so I've marked as the answer. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion best is to use response enum (code) that make sense to client. Apart from it returning message may increase the dataload on the WCF service.

E.g.

```
throw new FaultException<InvalidArgumentException>(new InvalidArgumentException(),Constants.MaxLengthFields.PhoneNumber)), Response.OrderIdMissing);

[DataContract, Serializable]
enum Response
{
 [EnumMember]
 OrderIdMissing,
 [EnumMember]
 ProductCodeInvalid,
}
```

There are several articles available on the web. Please go though them for more concrete information.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brajens/archive/2007/04/23/exception-handling-in-wcf-web-service.aspx

http://blogit.create.pt/blogs/marcosilva/archive/2008/05/18/Developing-a-WCF-Service-%5F2D00%5F-Fault-Exceptions-AND-FAULT-Contracts.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brajens/archive/2007/04/23/exception-handling-in-wcf-web-service.aspx